# Como restringir acceso mediante URL de los middleware a los modulos que no deben entrar

Tags: laravel

mi route web.php

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['guest']], function () {

    Route::get('/','Auth\LoginController@showLoginForm');
    Route::post('/', 'Auth\LoginController@login')->name('login');    
});

Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth']], function () {

Route::post('/logout', 'Auth\LoginController@logout')->name('logout');

Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index');


Route::group(['middleware' => ['Vendedor']], function () {

    ....


});

Route::group(['middleware' => ['Administrador']], function () {

    .....



  });
});
```

mi

---

Este es mi kernel.php

Tendria que modificar mi route.web?

namespace App\Http;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel as HttpKernel;

class Kernel extends HttpKernel
{
    /**
     * The application's global HTTP middleware stack.
     *
     * These middleware are run during every request to your application.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $middleware = [
        \App\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode::class,
        \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ValidatePostSize::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\TrimStrings::class,
        \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ConvertEmptyStringsToNull::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\TrustProxies::class,
    ];

```
/**
 * The application's route middleware groups.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $middlewareGroups = [
    'web' => [
        \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
        \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
        \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
        \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\AuthenticateSession::class,
        \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
        \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
    ],

    'api' => [
        'throttle:60,1',
        'bindings',
    ],
];

/**
 * The application's route middleware.
 *
 * These middleware may be assigned to groups or used individually.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $routeMiddleware = [
    'auth' => \App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
    'auth.basic' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\AuthenticateWithBasicAuth::class,
    'bindings' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
    'cache.headers' => \Illuminate\Http\Middleware\SetCacheHeaders::class,
    'can' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authorize::class,
    'guest' => \App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated::class,
    'signed' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ValidateSignature::class,
    'throttle' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests::class,
    'verified' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\EnsureEmailIsVerified::class,
    'Administrador' => \App\Http\Middleware\Administrador::class,
    'Vendedor' => \App\Http\Middleware\Vendedor::class,
];

/**
 * The priority-sorted list of middleware.
 *
 * This forces non-global middleware to always be in the given order.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $middlewarePriority = [
    \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
    \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
    \App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
    \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\AuthenticateSession::class,
    \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
    \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authorize::class,
];
```

}

Comment: ¿Qué intentas hacer y qué no funciona?

Comment: que el usuari vendedor no ingrese a los modulos que no tienen acceso, en este caso logra acceder mediante url

Answer (score 0):

Tienes que indicar en el controlador si la ruta esta protegida por accesso e indicarle el grupo al que pertenece. ¿Entiendo que estan probando el middelware group y no te funciona?.

Es posible que te falte este __construct en el controlador. Si puedes comparte el código del controlador.

```
/**
 * Create a new controller instance.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('auth');
}
```

Comment: es laravel 5.8 todo funciona normal, el detalle es que cuando con el vendedor entra mediante url a los modulos que no tiene permiso

Comment: Si te fijas en mi respuesta. Si tienes un controller para el vendedor que sería lo suyo. Añade arriba el construct que te respondí y en lugar de "auth" pon "Vendedor". ¿Puedes añadir el contenido del kernel.php?

Comment: ya añadi en la parte abajo puedes revisarlo

Answer (score 0):

Suponiendo que las rutas y archivos estén correctos, aquí tienes que modificar, no se si ya los tienes pero serian desde la clase `User`.

Recuerda que se hará una consulta a la DB por ende en tus registros de `Roles` ya deberias tener `["Administrador", "Vendedor"]`

Tablas involucradas `["User","Rol"]` la tabla `Rol` debe tener datos llenos que son `["Administrador", "Vendedor"]`

**Middleware Vendedor**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

class Vendedor
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next){
        if ($request->User()->hasRole('VENDEDOR')) {
            return $next($request);
        }
        else{
            abort(403, 'Como usuario '.\Auth::User()->roles->rol.' no tienes autorización, Debe ser un Usuario CAJA para ingresar.');
        }
    }
}
```

**Agregar a Clase User**

```
//lista de roles autorizados
    public function authorizeRoles($roles){  
        if (is_array($roles)) {
            return $this->hasAnyRole($roles) ||  abort(401, 'This action is unauthorized.');  
        }
        return $this->hasRole($roles) ||  abort(401, 'This action is unauthorized.');
    }
//basta un Rol
    public function hasAnyRole($roles){
        return null !== $this->roles()->whereIn('rol', $roles)->first();
    }
//Debe existir el rol
    public function hasRole($role){  
        return null !== $this->roles()->where('rol', $role)->first();
    }
//relacion con la tabla role [1:M] para [M:M] belongsToMany
    public function roles(){
        return $this->belongsTo('\App\Rol','idrol');
    }
```

Comment: hice lo todo pero el usuario vendedor sige accediendo mediante url a los modulos no admitidos